# SBT can't seem to download dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-metals

It appears that SBT can't find any of the dependencies needed, as well as both blooper and sbt can't seem to connect online to download any dependencies. I have checked if I have a proxy, if there are any inconsistent versions that are conflicting, and have fully reinstalled SBT, NVM, VSCode and everything else involved. I can't seem to figure out why it won't build and why it can't find any of the dependencies.

EDIT: Added Build.sbt file

I've removed the https:// from the repo links, but they are there in the normal error.

build.sbt file:

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.11"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "????"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "????"


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "ScalaJS-only",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test,
        scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
  ).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
```

Error Received:

```
PS C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend> sbt     
[info] Loading settings for project Backend-build-build-build from metals.sbt ...    
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\project\project\project
Oct 19, 2021 11:46:44 AM lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.org.jline.utils.Log logr    
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)    
[info] Updating    
[info] Resolved  dependencies    
[warn]    
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.    
[warn]          ch.epfl.scala:sbt-bloop:1.4.9 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)    
[warn]    
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:    
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:sbt:1.3.5    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\sbt-1.3.5.pom (expected SHA-1 88a91f2b0e535d0c22bc0b9dcc9b586bc6b7a109 in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\.sbt-1.3.5.pom__sha1, got aea457bc4067a7c2080a43791cdeb78b072ff5bb)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error] Error downloading ch.epfl.scala:sbt-bloop;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.4.9    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\ch\epfl\scala\sbt-bloop_2.12_1.0\1.4.9\sbt-bloop-1.4.9.pom (expected SHA-1 a9f21bf5ab89ca29d3acbac10c2a7ab74dbf8646 in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\ch\epfl\scala\sbt-bloop_2.12_1.0\1.4.9\.sbt-bloop-1.4.9.pom__sha1, got 3f431c638c39d83018ca88a348d1fb0e62db43a0)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\ch.epfl.scala\sbt-bloop\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\1.4.9\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ch.epfl.scala/sbt-bloop/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.9/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ch.epfl.scala/sbt-bloop/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.9/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error] Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\scala-library-2.12.10.pom (expected SHA-1 368a4cdefd92e20800076e97e3b58e722a7f942a in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\.scala-library-2.12.10.pom__sha1, got c0f5237f49d4b4a955c368a646e7eebc8ca3fc84)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.10/ivys/ivy.xml      
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.10/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:245)         
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$34(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)    
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)    
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)    
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)    
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)    
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)    
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)    
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2947)    
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)    
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)    
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)    
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)    
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)    
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)    
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)    
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)    
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)    
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)    
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:sbt:1.3.5    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\sbt-1.3.5.pom (expected SHA-1 88a91f2b0e535d0c22bc0b9dcc9b586bc6b7a109 in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\.sbt-1.3.5.pom__sha1, got aea457bc4067a7c2080a43791cdeb78b072ff5bb)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.5\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.5/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error] Error downloading ch.epfl.scala:sbt-bloop;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.4.9    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\ch\epfl\scala\sbt-bloop_2.12_1.0\1.4.9\sbt-bloop-1.4.9.pom (expected SHA-1 a9f21bf5ab89ca29d3acbac10c2a7ab74dbf8646 in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\ch\epfl\scala\sbt-bloop_2.12_1.0\1.4.9\.sbt-bloop-1.4.9.pom__sha1, got 3f431c638c39d83018ca88a348d1fb0e62db43a0)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\ch.epfl.scala\sbt-bloop\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\1.4.9\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ch.epfl.scala/sbt-bloop/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.9/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ch.epfl.scala/sbt-bloop/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.9/ivys/ivy.xml    
[error] Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10    
[error]   Not found    
[error]   Not found
[error]   wrong checksum: C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\scala-library-2.12.10.pom (expected SHA-1 368a4cdefd92e20800076e97e3b58e722a7f942a in C:\Users\????\Documents\Backend\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\.scala-library-2.12.10.pom__sha1, got c0f5237f49d4b4a955c368a646e7eebc8ca3fc84)    
[error]   not found: C:\Users\????\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.10\ivys\ivy.xml    
[error]   not found: repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.10/ivys/ivy.xml 
[error]   not found: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.10/ivys/ivy.xml
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: Hi Lucasino! Can you post also your build.sbt file?

Comment: sure thing @gianlucaaguzzi! Added to main post!

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix it ? I am bumping my head on the same issue. I can not tell what is conflicting or in general causing the `unresolved dependencies`. If I follow the link to the repo, (in my case artifactory) I am able to download the artifact without issue manually.